# Upgrading from redhat minor version 7.3 to 7.9

Tags: linux, rhel

I am pretty new to the Linux platform and I am trying to upgrade my VM from rhel 7.3 to 7.9. I understand that 7.3 is way older and I am wondering if I need to incrementally install all the minor versions 7.4, 7.5 ... etc before getting to 7.9?

I tried looking up such upgrades online but for the most part, I am only seeing upgrades from one minor version to the next minor version.

Also are there any known issues that may arise from this upgrade? Will appreciate any help I can get on this.

P.S: I am not trying to get to rhel 8 just yet :)

Comment: Normal procedure with a VM would be to do a fresh install and copy your data over. Obviously this approach might pose problems if your install is hugely customised.

Comment: @JeremyBoden A fresh install is only needed for a major release. This is just a minor release.

Comment: so a yum upgrade would work here? Is it possible that making this big yum might cause some packages to not work?

Comment: If you're worried you could contact RedHat. Presumably you have a support contract because you're running RHEL

Answer (score 3):

You can run `yum update` directly. You might want to update the kernel first, `yum update kernel kernel-*`.

Whatever you do, make sure you have enough disk space free, especially in `/boot`.

Answer (score 2):

You can perform a minor upgrade through:

```
sudo subscription-manager register --auto-attach
sudo yum --releasever=7.9 update
```